If we apply a constant perpetual perpendicular force on a brick kept on a floor, will it deform the brick?
Suppose a brick is kept on a floor and we apply a constant perpendicular pressure on it for an indefinite period, will it cause the brick to deform in any way?
Assume the pressure is small enough to not to break it immediately. Brick is brittle and pressure is applied by any material which can withstand the reaction by the floor. The floor is made up of concrete or the iron like in trains. Pressure is applied on the upper surface of the brick. Assume pressure can be applied indefinitely (assume forever). Deformation can be of any kind.
If yes then how small but non-zero , pressure can be applied for indefinite period without causing any deformation in the brick.
(I guess we can assume we can measure the deformation up to quantum scale.)

It would help if you were to clarify the problem somewhat. Is the floor rigid? Is the force applied at a single point? If so, where? Is the force applied perpendicularly downward or in some other direction perpendicular to a face of the brick? Is the object applying the force harder or softer than the brick? Why do you mean by deform? Would elastic compression count as deformation? Would the abrasion of surface particles count as deformation? Over what time period are you prepared to wait for the deformation to happen? What do you mean by 'quantum scale'? etc etc

Excellent answer was given. Why was it closed? Physics doesn’t have any model to handle this kind of situation no matter how much detail I give.

The long term effect of applying a load to a material is called 'creep' and it is irreversible (unlike elastic compression, say, which relaxes when the load is removed). As far as I know, there is no theoretical model to allow you to calculate the long term effects of creep in bricks. However, tests have been performed to quantify creep in masonry (where the creep is partly in the brick and partly in the mortar), so you could google that if you are interested.
You will see creep in many old buildings, where their timbers, brickwork and stonework have become permanently deformed over the centuries.

Interesting. Could you share a link with more information about creep?

Sounds like there is some sophisticated science going on with creep: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creep_(deformation)

I found a better link An overview of masonry creep

@Jagerber48, I'm not actually a materials scientist, but the Wikipedia article cited by grahamj42 strongly suggests that "creep" is the name for an effect, and not the name for any of the several different mechanisms that can cause the effect in different materials.

Deformation in old buildings is much more about the influence of weather, than the effects of the continuous force. As far as I know, if a force is not large enough to cause an immediate deformation, it will not do so after a long time either.

In addition to the existing answers, if you are interested in the long long term effects, Freeman Dyson discusses the behaviour of solids over astronomical time scales, in "Time without end: Physics and biology in an open universe".

As an example, consider the behavior of a lump of matter, a rock or a planet, after it has cooled to zero temperature. Its atoms are frozen into an apparently fixed arrangement by the forces of cohesion and chemical bonding. But from time to time the atoms will move and rearrange themselves, crossing energy barriers by quantum-mechanical tunneling.

He concludes that due to quantum tunneling, even at minimum temperature, solids will continue to deform under pressure, and calculates the speed of this effect (detailed calculations can be found in the paper):

On a time scale of 1065 yr, every
piece of rock behaves like a liquid, flowing into a spherical shape under the influence of gravity. Its atoms and molecules will be ceaselessly diffusing around like the molecules in a drop of water.


That is an interesting mechanism I had not thought of. I don't think I'll  live to see it but still. ;)

Oh, and on that timescale any creep is probably far outmatched by the expanding universe! ;-). And it has evaporated. And the protons may have decayed!

The brick will deform a small amount, according to its Young's modulus, immediately when the force is applied then it will stay at that deformation for as long as the force is applied. It will not deform any further as time goes on.

Not quite true. 'Creep' is a common effect in most building materials.

Solids are akin to liquids on very long timescales or very long distances when under stress

If the force is not close the maximum strength of the brick, this answer is right and accurate for any practical engineering purpose. Probably,

@Pere Well, which means it's the answer of an engineer. I have respect for engineers (I live in a house that is more than 100 years old and has not collapsed yet, so chapeau) -- but this is not an engineering site ;-).
